# Index match in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to match x value based on their row and column keys. In excel I have used INDEX & MATCH to fetch the correct values, but I am struggling to do the same in Pandas.

**Example:**

I want to add the highlighted value (saved in df2) to my df['Cost'] column.

I have got df['Weight'] & df['Country'] as keys but I don't know how to use them to look up the highlighted value in df2.

How can I fetch the yellow value into df3['Postage'], which I can then use to add that to my df['Cost'] column?

[image: Simplified Matrix]

I hope this makes sense. Let me know i should provide more info.

Edit - more info (sorry, I could not figure out how to copy the output from Jupyter):
[image]

When I run [93] I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample of your dataframes (df2, df3, etc)

Comment: show us the example in python pandas dataframe

Comment: Row and column indexing is called [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), similar to excel.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more info. Let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the highlighted value `1.75` simply

```
df2.loc[df2['Country']=='B', 3]
```

So generalizing the above and using country-weight key pairs from `df1`:

```
cost = []

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    country = df1.loc[i, 'Country']
    weight = df1.loc[i, 'Weight']
    cost.append(df2.loc[df2['Country']==country, weight]

df1['Cost'] = cost
```

Or much better:

```
df1['Cost'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2['Country']==x['Country'], x['Weight'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your last answer has helped me!  At first I was unable to use it because the row weight (int) was looking against the columns(str). Converting the weight into objects seem to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

for your case use (note [0] is needed to index into array)

```
row = df1.iloc[1]
df2[df2.Country == row.Country][row.Weight][0]
```

Hope this helps with .iloc and .loc

```
d = {chr(ord('A')+r):[c+r*10 for c in range(5)] for r in range(5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).transpose()
df.columns=['a','b','c','d','e']
print(df)
print("--------")
print(df.loc['B']['c'])
print(df.iloc[1][2])
```

output

```
    a   b   c   d   e
A   0   1   2   3   4
B  10  11  12  13  14
C  20  21  22  23  24
D  30  31  32  33  34
E  40  41  42  43  44
--------
12
12
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Comment: (Tks to @Leonardus Chen) - fixed to find row with df.Countr == row.Country.    And then index into arr by row.Weight value... then return [0] value.